# Nested decorators in Python defining simulation methods

Tags: python, python-decorators

Let's say we have three simulation methods:

```
def method1(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        #Implementation of some simulator backend
        #but as a toy model we just pass a string here
        return func(*args, simulation_method='method1', **kwargs)
    return wrapper


def method2(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        #Implementation of some simulator backend
        #but as a toy model we just pass a string here
        return func(*args, simulation_method='method2', **kwargs)
    return wrapper


def method3(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        #Implementation of some simulator backend
        #but as a toy model we just pass a string here
        return func(*args, simulation_method='method3', **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

such that we can call a `simulation` function with a specific method via

```
@method3
def simulation(simulation_method):
    #Implementation of some computation that needs to be simulated
    #but as a toy model we just print the following statement:
    print(f"Running simulation with {simulation_method} method")
```

which yields the output

```
"Running simulation with method3 method"
```

I now want to define a decorator called `MultiSimulation` that repeatedly calls the simulation function while using the given simulation methods with the following syntax:

```
@MultiSimulation
@method1
@method2
@method3
def simulation(simulation_method):
    print(f"Running simulation with {simulation_method} method")
```

This should give the output:

```
"Running simulation with method1 method"
"Running simulation with method2 method"
"Running simulation with method3 method"
```

I am stuck with the definition of MultiSimulation and would be glad to get some help here. Thanks!

I tried different variations such as

```
def MultiSimulation(func):
    def repeated_simulation(*args, **kwargs):
        simulation_methods = []
        if hasattr(func, '__wrapped__'):
            simulation_methods = func.__wrapped__.simulation_methods
        result = None
        for simulation_method in simulation_methods:
            kwargs['simulation_method'] = simulation_method
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return result
    repeated_simulation.simulation_methods = []
    repeated_simulation.__wrapped__ = func
    return repeated_simulation
```

but I don't get any output.

Comment: Are you ok to change your decorators ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Decorator rework required to keep decorator stacking

With the rework, here what you can get:

```py
@MultiSimulation
@method1
@method2
@method3
def simulation(simulation_method):
    print(f"Running simulation with {simulation_method} method")
    return simulation_method

print(simulation())
# Running simulation with method1 method
# Running simulation with method2 method
# Running simulation with method3 method
# ['method1', 'method2', 'method3']
```

You need to update your decorators this way:

```py
def method1(func):
    def wrapper1(*args, simulation_method="method1", **kwargs):
        return func(*args, simulation_method=simulation_method, **kwargs)

    return wrapper1
```

And you need this decorator:

```py
def MultiSimulation(func):
    def repeated_simulation(*args, **kwargs):
        tmp_fct = func
        results = []
        while tmp_fct:
            try:
                results.append(tmp_fct(*args, **kwargs))
            except TypeError:
                pass
            try:
                tmp_fct = tmp_fct.__closure__[0].cell_contents
            except TypeError:
                break
        return results

    return repeated_simulation
```

With this rework of decorators, it's possible to use your original style while getting the return values of the different simulation if necessary.

```py
def method1(func):
    def wrapper1(*args, simulation_method="method1", **kwargs):
        return func(*args, simulation_method=simulation_method, **kwargs)

    return wrapper1


def method2(func):
    def wrapper2(*args, simulation_method="method2", **kwargs):
        return func(*args, simulation_method=simulation_method, **kwargs)

    return wrapper2


def method3(func):
    def wrapper3(*args, simulation_method="method3", **kwargs):
        return func(*args, simulation_method=simulation_method, **kwargs)

    return wrapper3


def MultiSimulation(func):
    def repeated_simulation(*args, **kwargs):
        tmp_fct = func
        results = []
        while tmp_fct:
            try:
                results.append(tmp_fct(*args, **kwargs))
            except TypeError:
                pass
            try:
                tmp_fct = tmp_fct.__closure__[0].cell_contents
            except TypeError:
                break
        return results

    return repeated_simulation


@MultiSimulation
@method1
@method2
@method3
def simulation(simulation_method):
    print(f"Running simulation with {simulation_method} method")
    return simulation_method


print(simulation())
# Running simulation with method1 method
# Running simulation with method2 method
# Running simulation with method3 method
# ['method1', 'method2', 'method3']
```

Answer (score 3):

When you're stacking decorators you should note that they are decorated from bottom to the top. This means `method3` decorates the `simulation` and `method2` decorates "*this decorated function*" not the `simulation` itself. But as you've shown in your question you need to **"repeat"** the function with different decorators. Of course there are ways to do so but I would rather not doing it that way.

You can instead pass your simulation methods to `MultiSimulation` like:

```py
@MultiSimulation(method1, method2, method3)
```

Here is an implementation:

```py
def method1(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, simulation_method="method1", **kwargs)
    return wrapper

def method2(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, simulation_method="method2", **kwargs)
    return wrapper

def method3(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, simulation_method="method3", **kwargs)
    return wrapper

def MultiSimulation(*simulation_methods):
    def decorator(fn):
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            return [m(fn)(*args, **kwargs) for m in simulation_methods]
        return inner
    return decorator

@MultiSimulation(method1, method2, method3)
def simulation(simulation_method):
    print(f"Running simulation with {simulation_method} method")

simulation()
```

output:

```
Running simulation with method1 method
Running simulation with method2 method
Running simulation with method3 method
```

Comment: I prefer this style to the decorator stacking.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I have to agree with Dorian Turba, that this approach is nicer than what I had in mind initially! I am fairly new with using decorators and learned something new from you.

Comment: @LinLin Added some explanation for why you need something like this.

Answer (score 0):

I dislike using an arbitrary number of decorators, since it tends to get messy and order matters when placing them. Here, I would use a class-based decorator that supports multiple decorators in it's constructor:

```
class MultiSimulation:
    def __init__(self, *methods):
        self.methods = methods

    def __call__(self, func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return [method(func)(*args, **kwargs) for method in self.methods]
        return wrapper


def method1(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, simulation_method='method1', **kwargs)
    return wrapper


def method2(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, simulation_method='method2', **kwargs)
    return wrapper


def method3(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, simulation_method='method3', **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@MultiSimulation(method1, method2, method3)
def simulation(simulation_method):
    print(f"Running simulation with {simulation_method} method")

simulation()
```

Running this code yields:

```
"Running simulation with method1 method"
"Running simulation with method2 method"
"Running simulation with method3 method"
```

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate your solution which results in the same syntax as described in the answer from S.B. The class-based construction looks really interesting! I also prefer this approach to what I initially had in mind.